# Ocupar todo el espacio disponible en las columnas

Tags: css, bootstrap

Estoy realizando una maquetación de una vista web con un contenedor, dentro de el, tres columnas y un footer, estoy tratando de que aunque las columnas estén vacías que ocupen todo el espacio disponible hasta llegar al footer, he intentado lograrlo con `flexbox` pero no consigo que lo ocupe.

No puedo usar unidades absolutas ya que el tamaño de la pantalla es variable y quedaría mal.

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0 172px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
*{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center">
          <p class="text-center">footer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

> **¿Cómo puedo hacer para que las columnas ocupen hasta el footer?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se me ocurre usar la clase h-100 (altura 100% del padre), pero tienes que ponerlo en todos los elementos anidados para que funcione. En el wrapper he usado vh-100 (100% del viewport, es decir, 100% de la vista)

```css
footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 50px 0 172px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
*{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper vh-100">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-4 h-100">col 1</div>
      <div class="col-4 h-100">col 2</div>
      <div class="col-4 h-100">col 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center">
          <p class="text-center">footer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Una solución sería hacerlo mediante `display: grid`. Suponiendo que conocemos el alto que va a tener el `<footer>` podrías asignar dicho alto a la fila y a la fila que ocupa el `.wrapper` asignarle **1fr** para que trate de ocupar el espacio restante.

Para eso debemos hacer que `.row` ocupe `height: 100%` y el `body` un `height: 100vh` para que tenga un tamaño que no sea *auto* y así poder repartir todo el espacio.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 50px;
}

.wrapper .container .row{
  height: 100%;
}

*{
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">col 1</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 2</div>
      <div class="col-4">col 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row" >
        <div class="col-12 justify-content-center">
          <p class="text-center">footer</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero he validado la de pablo porque considero que es mas adecuada por usar clases de bootstrap, aun así también considero válida tu respuesta!